# Unable to start rmi server when codebase used

Tags: java, windows, rmi

```
    CalculationServerRegistrationService server = new CalculationServerRegistrationService();
    ICalculationServerRegistrationService stub  = (ICalculationServerRegistrationService) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(server, RMI_PORT);
    // Bind the remote object's stub in the registry
    Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
    registry.bind("ICalculationServerRegistrationService", stub);
    new RMIServerTimeoutChecker().run();
}
```

When I start rmiregistry command on the same machine without arguments, but inside D:/git/nnCloud/BE/nnCloudRESTService/target/classes folder, everything works fine. However, since I need two servers from different programs, I want to have single rmiregistry with two codebases so there is need to specify it explicitly instead of running two "rmiregistry" commands in different directories.

The only solution I see is to run

> rmiregistry -J-Djava.rmi.server.codebase="file:/D:/git/nnCloud/BE/nnCloudRESTService/target/classes file:/D:/git/nnCloud/BE/nnCloudRESTService/target/classes"

After doing so my app crashes at registry.bind.

```
java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mycompany.nncloudrestservice.serverservice.ICalculationServerRegistrationService
```

Comment: You got a ClassNotFoundException; most likely that means in one of your setups, the **classpath** is not as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

The codebase doesn't tell the current JVM where to find classes. The CLASSPATH does that. The codebase tells the downstream JVMs where to find the classes.

The correct here solution is to run each JVM that exports and binds remote objects with the appropriate `java.rmi.server.codebase` argument. Not the Registry.

Comment: setting -Djava.rmi.server.codebase for jvm also doesn't work.

Comment: Setting it for the server JVM? Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem after running rmiregistry from code, after placing LocateRegistry.createRegistry